# Am I a bad GM or are my players out of control?

Tags: stars-without-number

I just started GMing my first-ever *Stars Without Number* game.

I decided I’d have a session zero and walk my players through the character creation, as they were casual and had never used the system either.  I knew they were a rambunctious group, so I made a few minor rule exceptions, and then one player had to leave.

I stayed with the second player to walk them through the equipment buying process, and they seemed very confused with the idea that you are the creator of your character and can create what you want (within reason) and kept asking me to “just roll the dice” or “just decide for me”!  I tried explaining this basic idea to them, but then I realized I couldn’t.

This is one of my first games, and with friends also, so I am questioning if I am a decent GM or not.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already. Unfortunately, this seems like a totally opinion-based question, which isn't really suited to the Stack Exchange format.

Comment: It would be better to ask for ways of dealing with the situation. We don't know enough about you or your players to judge your quality as a GM. Even if we did the question would not be on topic. [Edit] the question, if you want advice on dealing with the situation.

Comment: Have you ever GM'ed other TTRPG before, like DnD, pathfinder? You said one player had to leave when you do minor rule exception, why? And most importantly, **how many players are playing, including the GM**?

Comment: Can you give us a few more details on the rules you made and why one player left?

Comment: @Vylix I removed part of your comment. It is inappropriate to expect the asker to educate us about the game—those who don’t know the game should not be answering, or trying to help the question clarify mechanical details. (“Help” to clarify a question from non-experts can often not make sense, or is actually incorrect, and may actually confuse things worse). (For the record, the answers to the removed parts are: that’s not true of most RPGS; no, SWN does not; sure, but suggesting doing that in a comment is starting to write an answer in a comment. None of those should be edited into the Q.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie understood. I'm not suggesting it, it is asked more in the spirit of "what have you tried", "have you tried this", I can see how it can be taken as an answer, though.